# how can i rotate a body with a tween?

Tags: javascript, canvas, game-physics, tween, matter.js

i'm trying rotate a body that i had created, but it's appear rotated when refresh the page, i use matter js (http://brm.io/matter-js/) and tween js (https://www.createjs.com/tweenjs), matter js don't has tween, so for that reasson i used tween js, but don´t works correctly

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //walls
    barra_izquierda_vaso_moleculas = Bodies.rectangle(200,200,10,200,{isStatic: true});
    barra_derecha_vaso_moleculas = Bodies.rectangle(500,200,10,200,{isStatic: true});
    barra_inferior_vaso_moleculas = Bodies.rectangle(350,300,300,10,{isStatic: true});

   //construction of my body
   vaso_moleculas = Body.create({
      parts: [barra_izquierda_vaso_moleculas, barra_derecha_vaso_moleculas, barra_inferior_vaso_moleculas],
      restitution: 0,
      friction: 0,
      frictionStatic: 0,
      frictionAir: 0,
      inertia: Infinity,
      mass: 1,
      isStatic: true,
   });

   // add to world
   World.add(world, vaso_moleculas);

   //tween
   createjs.Tween.get(vaso_moleculas).to(2, 9000);
});
```

Comment: I think you need to indicate position properties by createjs.Tween.get(vaso_moleculas).to({x: 400}, 9000); or properties of that kind.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw your shape using [p5.js](https://p5js.org/reference/) and in your `draw()` loop, set your background with a lower alpha, such as `background( 0, 32 )`. This will create the illusion of motion blur or tweening. You can see it [here](https://preview.redd.it/i5xizuydbcn01.gif?width=450&s=1d643928530a9c24a434f5793a36535177efb51e), kind of.